# ST_Touches for more than one geometry again

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I do have a similar problem as described in [Stack Exchange article](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/62525/st-touches-for-more-than-just-one-geometry) ... the whole story is a bit complex: what I really want is to create polygon-skeleton with ST_ApproximateMedialAxis but this one returns "straight skeleton of Polygon with point touching rings is not implemented" - which indicates that I have invalid polygons in my data.

Looking for a way to identify these polygons I carried on with the following PostGIS statements:

```
-------  create outer and inner rings  ----------
    --- outer rings 
    CREATE TABLE skeleton_tests.dump_outer_rings AS 
    SELECT 
          b.id,
         b.path AS gid,
          b.geom ::geometry(Polygon) as geom 
        FROM  
          (SELECT 
                    id,
                  (ST_DumpRings(geom)).*
                    FROM skeleton_tests.dump_gehst_ta_klein) b
    WHERE b.path[1] =0;  -- OUTER rings ARE = 0
    
    --- inner rings 
    CREATE TABLE skeleton_tests.dump_inner_rings AS 
    SELECT 
          b.id,
         b.path AS gid,
          b.geom ::geometry(Polygon) as geom 
        From 
          (SELECT 
                   id,
                    (ST_DumpRings(geom)).*
                    FROM skeleton_tests.dump_gehst_ta_klein) b
    WHERE b.path[1] > 0; -- >0 means inner ring
```

which identifies the ring-types and is just a preparatory step - to give you an idea of my input data for the next steps.
The following two versions of finding touching parts of inner rings raise my confusion ...

This one does identify a couple of touching inner rings:

```
--- Inner Ring touches outer Ring   / with cross join lateral "iteration"
SELECT
 a.id,
 c.id,
 a.geom,
 c.geom
FROM skeleton_tests.dump_outer_rings as a
CROSS JOIN LATERAL 
  (
  SELECT 
     b.id,
     b.geom
  FROM skeleton_tests.dump_inner_rings AS b
  where ST_TOUCHES(st_boundary(a.geom), b.geom)) AS c
  ORDER BY a.id;
```

But this one - which would be much faster - doesn't find any touching parts when using ST_TOUCHES but it does find some when using ST_INTERSECTS:

```
SELECT a.id, b.id 
    FROM
   skeleton_tests.dump_outer_rings AS a INNER JOIN skeleton_tests.dump_inner_rings AS b 
   ON ST_intersects(a.geom, b.geom) 
   WHERE a.id != b.id;
```

Depending on the data it could make a difference in finding intersecting vs. touching parts!
Any hint about that phenomenon?

Comment: Message "straight skeleton of Polygon with point touching rings is not implemented" does not mean that such polygons are invalid, just that the algorithm cannot handle them. But for you it is just the same, pity.

Comment: it's a pitty indeed, because postgis stops processing at that point ...

Comment: The explanation of the difference between intersect and touches is in the docs - st_touches - `Returns TRUE if A and B intersect, but their interiors do not intersect. Equivalently, A and B have at least one point in common, and the common points lie in at least one boundary. For Point/Point inputs the relationship is always FALSE, since points do not have a boundary.` https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Touches.html

Comment: thx for explanation - but my problem is that my CROSS JOIN LATERAL statement which uses ST_Touches returns several true results while the one with the INNER JOIN should return the same result when using ST_Touches -> but doesn't - it provides an empty result. a have to switch over to ST_Intersects within the INNER JOIN version to get a valid result. my test-data consists of a number of polygons and some of them with inner rings that touch the outer ring at exactly one single point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first query you are testing:

```
ST_TOUCHES(st_boundary(a.geom), b.geom))
```

whereas in the second query you are testing

```
ST_intersects(a.geom, b.geom)
```

In fact, those are both wrong!

First of all, since the `ST_DumpRings` return shells and holes as polygons (for some unknown reason), `ST_Boundary` needs to be used to extract the boundary ring linework (otherwise, the test is compromised due to presence of polygon interior areas).  These needs to be done on **both** inputs to the test.

Second, you need to use `ST_Intersects` instead of `ST_Touches`.  The reason is that the definition of [`ST_Touches`](https://postgis.net/docs/manual-dev/ST_Touches.html) is:

> Returns TRUE if A and B intersect, but their interiors do not intersect.

This means that `ST_Touches` is not useful for checking whether rings touch,
since any touch point is in the interior of the ring linework.  For instance, in this example of touching rings the result is `false`:

```
SELECT ST_Touches('LINEARRING (100 100, 100 300, 300 100, 100 100)', 
  'LINEARRING (200 200, 150 200, 150 150, 200 150, 200 200)');

 st_touches 
------------
 f
```

[image]

Instead, using `ST_Intersects` is the correct way to test whether rings touch:

```
 SELECT ST_Intersects('LINESTRING (100 100, 100 300, 300 100, 100 100)', 
   'LINESTRING (200 200, 150 200, 150 150, 200 150, 200 200)');

 st_intersects 
---------------
 t
```

So the test condition should be:

```
ST_Intersects( ST_Boundary(a.geom), ST_Boundary(b.geom))
```

Answer (score 0):

Touching inner rings are OK for the OGC rules but invalid for ESRI. So maybe you could find them with ST_IsValid, ST_IsValidReason, or ST_IsValidDetail by using the ESRI flag https://postgis.net/docs/ST_IsValidDetail.html.

> The optional flags parameter is a bitfield. It can have the following
> values:
>
> 0: Use usual OGC SFS validity semantics.
>
> 1: Consider certain kinds of self-touching rings (inverted shells and
> exverted holes) as valid. This is also known as "the ESRI flag", since
> this is the validity model used by those tools. Note that this is
> invalid under the OGC model.

Comment: thx for the hint - i will check that asap. but still I am wondering why those two different approaches don't follow the same behaviour ...

Comment: Because the filter conditions are different, as explained.